# Click a button programmatically

Tags: vb.net, winforms, button

I want to code a `button` that programmatically clicks the other `button` when I click it.

For example, I have two buttons named `Button1` and `Button2`, what I wanted to do is that immediately after I click `Button1`, it should click `Button2`. Is this possible?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

```
Protected Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
        Button2_Click(Sender, e)
End Sub
```

This Code call button click event programmatically

Comment: I call this event from a BackgroundWorker and must to change the event from Private to Friend and then Invoke it but it works.

Comment: Even though this answer is accepted, I think **this is not the anwer to the question; this code is not robust**. This simply calls the function `Button2_Click()`, which only happens to be the function handling the event. It does not trigger the actual event.

Answer (score 20):

Best implementation depends of what you are attempting to do exactly. Nadeem_MK gives you a valid one. Know you can also:

1. raise the `Button2_Click` event using `PerformClick()` method:

   ```
   Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
       'do stuff
       Me.Button2.PerformClick()
   End Sub
   ```
2. attach the same handler to many buttons:

   ```
   Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As System.EventArgs) _
       Handles Button1.Click, Button2.Click
       'do stuff
   End Sub
   ```
3. call the `Button2_Click` method using the same arguments than `Button1_Click(...)` method (**IF** you need to know which is the sender, for example) :

   ```
   Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
       'do stuff
        Button2_Click(sender, e)
   End Sub
   ```

Comment: I love this - the PerformClick method is so elegant.  Thanks!

Comment: Note that `Me.Button2.PerformClick()` works for any number of event handlers attached to `Button2.Click` (e.g. another form might have attached this event with `AddHandler`), where as `Button2_Click(sender, e)` calls a specific handler.

Answer (score 5):

The best practice for this sort of situation is to create a method that hold all the logics, and call the method in both events, rather than calling an event from another event;

```
Protected Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click

        LogicMethod()

End Sub

Protected Sub Button2_Click(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click

        LogicMethod()

End Sub

Private Sub LogicMethod()

     // All your logic goes here

End Sub
```

In case you need the properties of the EventArgs (e), you can easily pass it through parameters in your method, that will avoid errors if ever the sender is of different types. But that won't be a problem in your case, as both senders are of type Button.

Comment: doesn't repeat use of this, fill up the stack?  Since it never finishes the first click?

Answer (score 2):

Let say button 1 has an event called

```
Button1_Click(Sender, eventarg)
```

If you want to call it in Button2 then call this function directly.

```
Button1_Click(Nothing, Nothing)
```

Answer (score 0):

in c# this is working :D

```
protect void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e){
    button2_Click(button2, null);
}

protect void button2_Click(object sender, EventeArgs e){
    //some codes here
}
```

for vb.net

```
Protected Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs)   Handles Button1.Click
    Button2_Click(Sender, e)
End Sub

Protected Sub Button2_Click(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs)   Handles Button2.Click
    //some codes here
End Sub
```

Comment: `button2_Click(button2, null);` <-- This is C# - Null is not the same in vb.net and no `;`