# How do I call a click event with the name of the click event as string

Tags: .net, vb.net

I have a listbox with names of click events.
I'd like to loop through the listbox and execute each of these events.
I have tried the following, but this does not work.

```
Private Sub btnRunSelectedRoutines_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnRunSelectedRoutines.Click
    For i As Integer = 0 To ListBoxSelectedButtons.Items.Count - 1
        ListBoxSelectedButtons.Items(i).ToString_Click(sender, New System.EventArgs)
    Next
End Sub
```

I call click events in the following way, which works without problem.

```
Private Sub btnRunSelectedRoutines_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnRunSelectedRoutines.Click
    btnA_Click(sender, New System.EventArgs)
    btnB_Click(sender, New System.EventArgs)
    btnC_Click(sender, New System.EventArgs)
End Sub
```

The names in the listbox are as in the example above "btnA, btnB, btnC"

**My question is:**
Is there a way of calling a click event with values from a listbox (strings)?

Comment: Maybe this article may help and is what you need: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19151515/click-a-button-programmatically

Answer (score 1):

You can add any type of item to a `ListBox`, not just strings. Let's create a class for this purpose:

```vb
Private Class EventHandlerDisplay
    Public ReadOnly Property Text As String
    Public ReadOnly Property Click As EventHandler

    Public Sub New(text As String, click As EventHandler)
        Me.Text = text
        Me.Click = click
    End Sub

    Public Overrides Function ToString() As String
        Return Text
    End Function
End Class
```

It has two properties. One for a text and one for an event handler. The text is also returnd in `ToString`.

Now, we can add our event handlers to the listbox like this

```vb
Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    ListBoxSelectedButtons.Items.
        Add(New EventHandlerDisplay("BtnA_Click", AddressOf BtnA_Click))
    ListBoxSelectedButtons.Items.
        Add(New EventHandlerDisplay("BtnB_Click", AddressOf BtnB_Click))
    ListBoxSelectedButtons.Items.
        Add(New EventHandlerDisplay("BtnC_Click", AddressOf BtnC_Click))
End Sub
```

We can then call the selected click routines like this

```vb
Private Sub BtnRunSelectedRoutines_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnRunSelectedRoutines.Click
    For Each item As EventHandlerDisplay In ListBoxSelectedButtons.SelectedItems
        item.Click.Invoke(Me, EventArgs.Empty)
    Next
End Sub
```

Note: by default, the `ListBox` displays items by calling their `ToString` method. This is why we have overridden `ToString` above.

We are storing the Click routines as [Delegates](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/programming-guide/language-features/delegates/). Therefore, we do not have to call the routines by name or to use Reflection. We can [call the delegates directly](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/programming-guide/language-features/delegates/how-to-invoke-a-delegate-method).

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can use reflection:

```
Imports System.Reflection
```

[...]

```
Dim mInfo As MethodInfo

For i As Integer = 0 To ListBoxSelectedButtons.Items.Count - 1
    mInfo = GetType(ContainerClass).GetMethod(ListBoxSelectedButtons.Items(i).ToString())
    mInfo.Invoke()
Next
```

read some documentation in : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.type.getmethod?view=net-6.0

And of course you can filter the Controls array in the form and perform a click on the desired ones

(remember to Import System.Link)

```
Dim cButtons = Controls.OfType(Of Button).Where(Function(c) ListBoxSelectedButtons.Items.Contains(c.Name))

For Each bt In cButtons 
    bt.PerformClick()
Next
```